# onMouseOver knows what it hovers over

Tags: reactjs

I have a onMouseOver event that triggers an alert box. See the code below. However, it will trigger that event even if I hover the mouse to the right of the text. That is part of my problem. All I want is to have it triggered when hovering over the text itself.

The next issue is, depending on which li element I hover over, I need to to trigger an event that takes into considering which piece of text it is hovering over. For example, if I hovered over the first item in the White Advantages image, it would know that it is about being uncastled and act accordingly. If it was the second item, it would know it is about semi-open files and then act accordingly. How do I do this?

```
<li style={litags} onMouseOver={() => alert('hover')}>
     <span style={tags} key={index1}>
     {name1}
     </span>
 </li>
```

[image: Sample list]

Comment: move your `onMouseOver` event handler to the `span` instead of the `li`

Comment: That worked great, thanks! I now need to find out how to get it to know what the text was that it hovered over.

Comment: your `onMouseOver` function takes an [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event) as an argument. you should be able to the text of your span using `event.target.text`

Comment: I tried this but it alerts undefined. `onMouseOver={event => alert(event.target.text)}` Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: Should be target.textContent

Comment: Hey, that works perfectly, thanks!